# Java Thread Pool Synchronization

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, thread-synchronization

I would like to perform the following algorithm - this must be done in Java

```
for(int i = 0; i< 100; i++){
    create 8 threads which perform a task
    wait for all threads to finish
}
```

It is desirable that threads are not continuously created and destroyed due to overheads (and the fact that each thread will have <20milli seconds of work), which brought about the idea of Thread Pools[1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html). I also know that using Executable[2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html), one can call shutdown, and then awaitTermination. However it is not desirable in this case due to the loop. Thus how can thread synchronization occur?

I would like to synchronize threads in the thread pool as would be done using a traditional thread's join() method.

Comment: The question is not clear.  You create 100 times 8 threads or you process 100 tasks in 8 threads?  What do you need to synchronize (you synchronize the data, not the threads)?

Comment: Are you sure you have to wait for all 8 tasks to finish before starting a new task?    If you want 8 threads because you have an 8 core machine then you simply need to use an 8 thread ThreadPool.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried looking at a [Cyclic Barrier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html). It is optimized  to allow a group of threads to stop and wait till everyone has reached a common barrier. I can't seen any reason why it can't be used with known number of pooled threads with references to a common barrier. There could be some additional complexity if you need to synchronize on the callback invoked with the barriers `await()` count is reached because it executes in a different thread.

Comment: Thank you, this looks very helpful. I will try coupling the Cyclic Barrier with Thread Pools and post with my results. However I want to point out that you are incorrect in assuming that I am interested in the functionality, I simply have an application I would like to make faster through threading which needs synchronization.

Answer (score 2):

You need to stick all your tasks in a queue, then feed the queue to a [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html).  You tell the thread pool executor how many threads to use and it takes care of executing the tasks.

Comment: However this does not solve the problem of synchronization, if I am not mistaken?

Comment: If you really need it (and if so, why is your task list not a multiple of 8?), you can put jobs in the task queue 8 at a time and override `ThreadPoolExecutor.afterExecute()` to check if all tasks have completed and, if so, add another 8 to the queue.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the fork/ join framework of jdk 7.

Comment: Thank you, I had read about the Fork/Join Framework previously here (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html) but was dissuaded from using it as it is intended for recursive algorithms, while the algorithm I am trying to implement is much easier to implement iteratively. Also I have a fixed number of threads I would like this to run on, while this algorithm is better suited for dividing a task into small units of work and allowing Fork/Join to figure out how to best use the resources accordingly.